# Data structure with type-specific, but without template

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I have noticed that most (all?) of C++ data structures that can store a user defined type use template:

```
std::vector<T>, std::unordered_map<T....>, etc.
```

It seems to me that it is required, otherwise those data-structures will have to return as the sinister pointer `void*` that users have to cast manually as follows:

```
std::vector a; 
int b;
a.push_back(b);
static_cast<int>(a.get(0));
```

Is it possible to not use the template?  Are there any other alternative approaches?

**Edit:** 
Many comments suggest that without template, it is impossible / impractical.  (Thank!)

What if I limited `<T>` to be a real pointer (e.g. not int/float), will it still be impractical?

Comment: `static_cast` on get is only a small part of the problem. In your example, what would the declaration of the hypothetical `vector::push` be?

Comment: It is possible, but that would mean adopting a pure C-style strategy. The main example I can give you is the way linked lists and RB trees are implemented within the Linux kernel

Comment: Using templates you can get containers storing elements by value. In case of `void *` it wouldn't be an option...

Comment: What is it about templates that you feel you have to avoid them? They are an excellent solution to this problem.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you feel that the template prevents you from solving? Do you need a heterogenous or something?

Comment: Why do you want "to not use the template"? This really seems like an XY question. Anyway, optimised stdlib implementations will use `void *` as a main base for pointer-type specialisations wherever possible, so if you're trying to do any premature optimisation, they've already beaten you to it!

Comment: It is not impossible. It is not impractical. It depends on your problem. How do you know what type is associated with your data when you extract an entry from the container? Which leads to tagged `union`. And ... I think `reinterpret_cast` on `void*` is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to not use the template?

Yes. It is possible to define a general data structure, that allows grouping <sup><-- I don't know what verb to use here</sup> objects of any type, without using a template.

There is the "C way" (templates do not exist in C). The C way is to use `void*`. You are apparently already familiar, but for other readers of the answer, `void*` is a special pointer type, that can point to an object of any type. When you use `void*` to refer to an object, you essentially throw away all type safety that the language offers.

I don't think there are any non-template containers <sup>†</sup> in the standard library. However, if it is not too much to use the offered templates to instantiate `std::vector<void*>` or similar, then you can certainly use such template instance to store pointers to any objects.

Templates are strongly preferred to `void*` because templates do not throw type safety out of the window. Templates are much easier to use correctly.

<sup>†</sup> Not yet. But `std::any` is planned to be introduced in C++17. It can be used in stead of `void*`. Using `std::any` you still throw away compile time type safety, but at least you retain run time safety (you'll get an exception instead of potentially dragons when you have a bug). And unlike `void*`, `std::any` manages the memory of the stored object. Note that while `std::any` is not a template, most of its member functions are.

---

> Are there any other alternative approaches?

Besides templates and `void*`? Technically, you could also use macros to generate different versions of same program, similarly to instantiating a template. This is sometimes used in C. There is no reason do this in C++, because templates are better in every way.

Comment: Hmmm grouping -> storing a collection of?

Comment: @TimStraubinger That's a fitting word for containers that indeed store the objects (like the standard containers), but we are also considering `void*`. When we use `void*` we aren't *"storing"* the objects. We just refer to them. This is why I have trouble coming up with a word describing the use of data structures in general.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you an example why can it be dangerous to use such an collection. Consider the code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using anyvector = std::vector<void *>;

int main() {
   anyvector av;
   av.push_back(new int(10));
   std::cout << (*static_cast<int*>(av[0])) << std::endl;
}
```

the `av[0]` is a pointer to int created by old-fashioned c++ way using `new` keyword. As such one should free the memory allocated this way using `delete` keyword. But to do this the pointer should be first cast to the right type to let compiler know what is he really deleting in order to prevent from undefined behaviour.

To be clear I'm not saying it is impossible nor impractical but it require from the programmer full consciousness...

Comment: This is why things like `boost::any`, soon to be `std::any`, are templates with additional scaffolding to track the type, call the right `delete`r, etc. Doing this manually really doesn't seem worthwhile, as you indicated. By my understanding of "modern C++", anything that would require manual memory management, exotic casts, etc should be handled by the library or other carefully made wrappers; user code shouldn't do any.

Comment: Someone needs to write the libraries and the wrappers. User code (whatever this means) can also be a library.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on type erased structures.
As a minimal, working and naïve example:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct Container {
    struct B {
        virtual void operator()() = 0;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct D: B {
        D(T t): o{t} {}
        void operator()() override { o(); }
        T o;
    };

    template<typename T>
    void add(T t) {
        vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<B>{new D<T>{t}});
    }

    void operator()() {
        for(auto &ref: vec) (*ref)();
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> vec;
};

struct P {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "P" << std::endl; }
};

struct Q {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Q" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Container c;
    P p;
    Q q;
    c.add(p);
    c.add(q);
    c();
}
```

C++17 will probably bring in `std::any` and let you doing it easily.
Until then, you can use `boost::any` or an homemade type erased class like the one above.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that templates are the correct way to approach containers, `std::any` (or `boost::any`) when you can't use containers. However, just for the fun part I'd like to note that perfect type reconstruction is possible via exceptions. Note this is *very much ill-recommended*, I'm just adding this for completeness. In this case,

- your vector is like `std::vector<std::function<void()>>` (can be simplified),
- you push elements like `v.push_back([e](){ throw e; });` and
- you visit elements by, yuck, not less than `catch`ing the exception thrown by e.g. `try{ v[i](); } catch(EType& e) { ... }`.

This is ugly, don't do this, this is slow, don't do this.. but, on the other hand, it allows for perfect visitation (including inheritance, which you don't get with `type_info`), open hierarchies (which you don't get with `variant`), chaining of visitors, without the need for base class & additional virtual functions.

BIG FAT WARNING: you probably wouldn't pass my CR with such a code - it's just mentioned for fun and theoretical completeness.